# Playframework 2.2.x + Java +JPA - Separate Database for Unit Testing and Production

Tags: unit-testing, playframework, playframework-2.0, jpa-2.0

I am using Java + Playframework + JPA using PlayFramework 2.3-M1 for developing application.

I want to use MySQL database when I run the aplication, but when I run test using

```
activator test
```

I want to use in memory database H2.

How can this be done ?

Below is my

conf/META-INF/persistence.xml

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="prod" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <non-jta-data-source>prodDS</non-jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" 
                      value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"></property>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"></property>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

    <persistence-unit name="test" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <non-jta-data-source>TestDS</non-jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" 
                      value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"></property>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"></property>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

conf/application.conf

```
# Database configuration
# ~~~~~ 
# You can declare as many datasources as you want.
# By convention, the default datasource is named `default`
#
db.test.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.test.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play"
db.test.user=sa
db.test.password=""

db.test.jndiName=TestDS

jpa.test=testPersistenceUnit

db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://X.X.X.X/lb"
db.default.user=lb
db.default.password="lb"

#
# You can expose this datasource via JNDI if needed (Useful for JPA)
db.default.jndiName=DefaultDS


jpa.default=defaultPersistenceUnit


# Evolutions
# ~~~~~
# You can disable evolutions if needed
evolutionplugin=disabled

# Ebean configuration
# ~~~~~
# You can declare as many Ebean servers as you want.
# By convention, the default server is named `default`
#
ebean.default="models.*"
```

Is this the best approach to get it done?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So I used some mix/match approach for faster testing

1. I used separate configuration files for testing and production
2. I used two different JPA Persistence Units for Prod and Testing
3. Added overrode the config file for test execution in build.sbt
4. Utilized  to generate test schema
5. Utilized evolution to load test data fixtures into test data

Below are my files:

conf/test.conf

```
db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:lb"
db.default.user=lb
db.default.password=""

#
# You can expose this datasource via JNDI if needed (Useful for JPA)
db.default.jndiName=DefaultDS


jpa.default=testPersistenceUnit


# Evolutions
# ~~~~~
# You can disable evolutions if needed
#evolutionplugin=disabled
```

conf/application.conf

```
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://X.X.X.X/lb"
db.default.user=lb
db.default.password="lb"

#
# You can expose this datasource via JNDI if needed (Useful for JPA)
db.default.jndiName=DefaultDS

jpa.default=defaultPersistenceUnit

# Evolutions
# ~~~~~
# You can disable evolutions if needed
evolutionplugin=disabled
```

Then added following option to build.sbt file

build.sbt

```
javaOptions in Test += "-Dconfig.file=conf/test.conf"
```

Finally the persistence.xml file

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">

    <!--Persistence Unit for Production-->

    <persistence-unit name="defaultPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <non-jta-data-source>DefaultDS</non-jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"></property>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"></property>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

    <!--Persistence Unit for Testing-->

    <persistence-unit name="testPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <non-jta-data-source>DefaultDS</non-jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"></property>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"></property>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Finally I test it using

```
activator test
```

Thanks to users at play-framework google group for leads into achieving this.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not using HIbernate just Ebean, but overriding the db in a global test.conf was a good idea. Just as a side-note, Play will look in `conf/` automatically if you use `-Dconfig.resource=test.conf` instead.

Comment: @Blacklight Thanks for the feedback. Yes, I agree, but since lot of things were copied from my Jenkins build scripts, which needed full path to deploy to a remote server, i just kept it that way.

Comment: Thank you. All of this should be been part of the Play docs.
Its really difficult to setup multiple configurations for test and prod.

Comment: Hi, can you elaborate on how you implemented steps 4 and 5? Thanks!